# Datetime filter with olingo (odata v2)

Tags: java, odata, olingo

`Looking to filter result using datetime with odata v2 (implemented odata v2 using olingo )

tried below datetime filter but getting error

https://api01.dev.xyz.com/abc/Odata.svc/TableDTOs?$filter=SystemUpdateTime gt datetime'2023-06-16T15:01:25'

**error:**
class java.util.GregorianCalendar cannot be cast to class java.util.Date (java.util.GregorianCalendar and java.util.Date are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')

looks like need to write some custom filter in my java application using olingo any input on using existing filter or writing custom filter will be helpful

Note: Using odatav2 and Olingo-odata2 jars`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.